# How to change error colors for Komodo IDE color scheme

Tags: colors, komodo

I'm customizing color scheme, and almost everything working right.
Except command output tab is showing errors in red italic font, color settings for which I cannot find anywhere!
In font&color settings there are "fonts", "colors", "common syntax", "lang-specific" and "indicators" tabs, with drop-down selectors.
There is not one option that has red italic color assigned!!
Default font is white on blue.
Where could I find color settings for command output errors?

Answer (score 6):

Well, nobody is answering, and I found a hack that helps.
It seems, that there's really no gui menu option for error text color in command output, but there is setting in .ksf file for it.
I changed manually line that says

```
'Errors': {'Error lines': {'fore': 65535, 'hotspot': 1, 'italic': 0}},
```

where 'fore' is the foreground color, 'italic' is italic font, to what I wanted, and it worked.
I suppose, 'hotspot' means it's clickable, but I don't sure/don't care now.

Comment: If anyone is on MacOS and is wondering, I found my customized scheme .KSF file in ~/Library/Application Support/KomodoEdit/{version}/schemes/{name}.ksf

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late from the original post but I stumbled on this one while searching for this problem, it led me to the hint as to where to look in the GUI.

In version Komodo 9.0+

- Preferences > Colour Scheme
- Select the tab 'Language Specific'
- Select the 'Language Errors' (underneath Others)

The Element type Error lines seems to reflect STDERR